# Waiting a response in Thread via HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have a Function which sends url request to server and gets data. I'm able to get data but data is coming late as request is being sent in another Thread.

I want user to wait for the request (For login authentication). How do achieve this?

```
private String sendRequest(final String URL) {
     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
     ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

     new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;

            try {
                httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URL)
                        .openConnection();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                        httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());

                data = readStream(in);
                Log.i(TAG,"Respose from "+URL);
                System.out.println(data);

            } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException");
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
            } finally {
                if (null != httpUrlConnection)
                    httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
            }
       }                        
}).start();

return data;
}
```

I call above function like this

```
public JSONObject get(String URL){

        data = sendRequest(URL);        

        try {
            if(null!=data){
                returnJsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG,"Response data is null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnJsonObj;   
    }
```

How do I wait for a data in **get** Function.

Comment: Why not use `AsyncTask`?

Comment: You should use an asynctask for that. Here's a tutorial using asynctask to send and receive http data http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: How AsyncTask will update return data? I was facing issue with that hence trying with this method.

Comment: When using AsyncTask and while doing network request/response inside "doInBackground" method, you should put "Logging in" message on screen. When all communication ends, and you receive http response, background thread will end and process will enter into "onPostExecute" method. This is where you will log your user, hide message or shoe error.